# Localstack SQS can't be reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker-compose, amazon-sqs, localstack

I'm creating a spring boot application in order to publish messages to an AWS SQS queue running on Localstack, the following are the key files for my application:

**docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  aws:
    image: 'localstack/localstack'
    container_name: 'localstack'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs,sns,dynamodb
      - DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - ./localstack_bootstrap:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/
    networks:
      - websocket-network
  td-listener:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "create-queue.sh"
    depends_on:
      - aws
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    networks:
      - websocket-network

networks:
  websocket-network:
```

**Initialization script for SQS (sqs_boostrap.sh)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

# enable debug
# set -x

echo "configuring sqs"
echo "==================="
LOCALSTACK_HOST=localhost
AWS_REGION=us-east-1

create_queue() {
    local QUEUE_NAME_TO_CREATE=$1
    awslocal --endpoint-url=http://${LOCALSTACK_HOST}:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name ${QUEUE_NAME_TO_CREATE} --region ${AWS_REGION} --attributes VisibilityTimeout=30
}

create_queue "sample-queue"
```

**Spring boot application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8090

cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      static: us-east-1
    credentials:
      access-key: 12345
      secret-key: 12345
    end-point:
      uri: http://localstack:4566

td:
  sample:
    sqs:
      queue:
        url: http://localstack:4566/000000000000/sample-queue
        groupid: samples

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

And my java class trying to reach the SQS Queue:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ListQueuesResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageResult;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.UUID;

@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuoteMessageListener extends WebSocketConnectionHandler {

    private final AmazonSQS amazonSQS;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync;

    @Value("${td.sample.sqs.queue.url}")
    private String queueUrl;

    @Value("${td.sample.sqs.queue.groupid}")
    private String groupId;


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        log.info("Receive quote message {}", message.getPayload());

       SendMessageRequest request = null;

        try {
            request = new SendMessageRequest()
                    .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .withMessageBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message))
                    .withMessageGroupId(groupId);


            final SendMessageResult result = amazonSQS.sendMessage(request);

            log.info("Event message has been published in SQS with ID: {}.", result.getMessageId());

        } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            log.error("JsonProcessingException e : {} and stacktrace : {}", jpe.getMessage(), jpe);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception occurred while pushing event to sqs : {} and stacktrace ; {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        log.info("END");
    }
    
}
```

I tried multiple changes in order to reach the SQS queue, but I'm always getting the following error:

```
Region of queue URL http://localstack:4566/000000000000/sample-queue is ambiguous, got region us-east-1 from request
localstack.request.aws     : AWS sqs.SendMessage => 400 (AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue)
localstack.request.http    : POST /000000000000/sample-queue => 400
Exception occurred while pushing event to sqs : The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue;
```

I'll appreciate your hints or comments on the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace "http://localstack:4566" references in application.yml with "http://localhost:4566" for it to work. Oh also, I think default access key and pwd are local/local. I'd replace these just in case.